# General Topology, Bounded set related to point of accumulation

Tags: general-topology

Prove: Show that if $A$ is a bounded set then sup($A$) is an element of $A$ or a point of accumulation.

Definitions: Let $A$ be a partially ordered set $X$. An element $m\in X$ is a lower bound of $A$ if and only if $x\geq M \forall x\in A$. Similarly, an element $M\in x$ is an upper bound of $A$ if and only if $x \leq M \forall x\in A$. If $A$ has both an upper and lower bound, then it is said to be bounded. If some upper bound of $A$ proceeds every other upper bound of $A$, then it is called the least upper bound or supremum of $A$ denoted sup($A$). A point $p\in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point if and only if every open set $G$ containing $p$ contains a point of $A$ different from $p$.

Proof: Let $A$ be a bounded set, the sup($A$) is max of $A$ or any $M$, where $M$ is the least element which is greater or equal to $x$ $\forall x\in A$. Let $A\notin A$ or point of accumulation, then select a lower value than $M$ to be the maximum of $A$ which is possible as $M$ not an element nor a point of accumulation. This means $M$ is not the supremum thus contradicting our assumption. Hence $M$ must be an accumulated point or an element of $A$ if M is the supremum.

Not sure if this is right, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: To me the statement you wish to prove is concerned with the order topology, whereas your definition of accumulation point is implicitly using the metric/continuum property of $\mathbb{R}$. While this is fine when considering $\mathbb{R}$ with its metric/order topology (they are equivalent), this is not a good idea when your order topology does not have the continuum property, i.e. for all $x,y \in X$ such that $x<y$ there is a $z\in X$ such that $x<z<y$. My hint is that you should consider the cases where $X$ has the continuum property and where it does not.

Comment: I see, so would you recommend using a different definition of accumulation? I also do not really follow your hint can you clarify?

Comment: Check the first [line here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition) for a precise definition of limit/accumulation point. 

To clarify my hint, you already know that $\sup A$ exists, and by virtue of the order topology you can break the question down into a few cases. If you need more clarification I can upgrade my hint to an answer.

Comment: @Yeldarbskich yea if you could that would be great, also I changed my proof above not sure if it is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot seem to salvage much from your attempt at the proof, so I will give a proof of your original question followed by a corollary and an example. I also noted that my hints of thinking about the continuum property was too strong a condition to consider. I have fixed that in my proof.

> Let $A$ be a bounded subset of the totally ordered set $X$, where $X$ has the order topology. Show that if $\sup A$ exists, then either $ \sup A \in A$ or $\sup A$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

*Proof:* Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\sup A \not\in A$ and $\sup A$ is not an accumulation point. Since it is not an accumulation point then there is an element $x \in X$ such that $\sup A \in (x,\infty)$ and $(x,\infty)\cap A = \emptyset$, i.e. it is contained in an open set which does not intersect $A$. If $x \not\in A$ then that implies $a < x < \sup A$ for all $a \in A$, but this contradicts that $\sup A$ is the least upper bound. If $x \in A$, then since $(x,\infty)\cap A = \emptyset$ there are no elements of $A$ between $x$ and $\sup A$; furthermore since $\sup A \not\in A$ then that implies that $a \leq x$ for all $a \in A$. This also contradicts that $\sup A$ is the least upper bound. Having contradicted all possibilities, it must be that $\sup A \in A$ or $\sup A$ is an accumulation point.

> **Corollary:** Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Then $\sup A \in A$ or $\sup A$ is an accumulation point.

*Example:* Let $A = \lbrace 1-1/n : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \rbrace$ and $B=A \cup \lbrace 1 \rbrace$.

Clearly $A$ and $B$ are bounded since $A,B \subset [0,1]$. The supremum of $A$ is 1, however 1 is not a member of $A$. On the other hand, 1 is a member of $B$